# Fitting a linear regression model to a CSV matrix

Tags: numpy, pandas, scikit-learn

I am working with a quarterly data matrix as such:

```
Qtrs,Y,X,,,
1Q11, 252.0 , 0.0166 ,1,0,0
2Q11, 212.4 , 0.0122 ,0, 1 ,0
3Q11, 425.9 , 0.0286 ,0,0, 1 
4Q11, 522.3 , 0.0322 ,0,0,0
1Q12, 263.2 , 0.0185 ,1,0,0
2Q12, 238.6 , 0.0131 ,0, 1 ,0
3Q12, 411.3 , 0.0270 ,0,0, 1 
4Q12, 538.4 , 0.0343 ,0,0,0
1Q13, 272.0 , 0.0180 ,1,0,0
2Q13, 212.3 , 0.0122 ,0, 1 ,0
3Q13, 405.2 , 0.0257 ,0,0, 1 
4Q13, 495.8 , 0.0308 ,0,0,0
1Q14, 264.5 , 0.0179 ,1,0,0
2Q14, 211.2 , 0.0116 ,0, 1 ,0
```

I am using the following code to read the csv data file in and fit the model:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

data = pd.read_csv('C:/Filepath/Macro.csv')
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(data['X'], data['Y'])
```

However the error I get when executing the code is:

```
ValueError: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples: [ 1 14]
```

Any idea what basic error I am committing?

Answer (score 1):

sklearn models expect the `X` data (the predictor variables) to be 2D data of shape (n_samples, n_features).
So in this case, you can pass the X data as a dataframe by doing `data[['X']]` instead of `data['X']`:

```
In [24]: regressor.fit(data[['X']], data['Y'])
Out[24]: LinearRegression(copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, normalize=False)
```

As an explanation of the double square brackets: `data[['X']]` is the pandas way to specify you want to select a subset of your dataframe corresponding to this list of column names (in your case a list of one element), instead of `data['X']` which just returns that one column as a series:

```
In [27]: data['X'].shape
Out[27]: (14L,)

In [28]: data[['X']].shape
Out[28]: (14, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks @Joris.  Just to clarify the answer, if I had multiple predictor variables (say the next 3 columns after X), could I use [X] instead of [[X]].  Put another way, how would I include the next 3 predictor variable columns as predictors?

Comment: Why not also include the Y variable in double brackets [[Y]]?

Comment: On your first question, you can use the same syntax (list of column names within the `[]` getter), but then with multiple columns, which gives: `data[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']]`

Comment: On your second question: that would also work (you can try), but is not needed because `y` is expected to be one-dimensional if you have one target variable (so sklearn will recognize this case)